# Liferay Hook override current JS

Tags: javascript, hook, liferay

Is there a special tag i can use when creating a liferay hook that allows liferay to use my specific javascript over the default liferay javascript.

I want to override the liferay session.js with my own version in my hook.

So for overriding jsp you can use

```
<custom-jsp-dir>/custom_jsps</custom-jsp-dir>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd expect the non-theme-related js to be overridden just like JSPs. In fact, I've seen a hook for updating alloy-ui, and if memory doesn't serve me wrong, this has been done through exactly these mechanics.

Have you tried this but it didn't work or didn't you try it because you supposed it wouldn't work?

Comment: It Works a restart is required though.

Comment: Ok, now that you say this it's probably due to the minifier that processes the files and generates some heavily cached results. Once it's generated it looks like it won't be updated (until a restart).